# How to reassign the textures to my imported obj in blender?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

Recently Ive downloaded my maximo character created from blender with animations but when i reimport it back in blender, it does not show the textures.

The animations for the character were fine but it is in white color. Can someone shade some light on how i can reassign back my texture maps in blender? I am using cycles render.

Comment: What's maximo? A Software?

Answer (score 1):

OBJ files can contain your UV layout. So, providing you have made your UV layout on the character, just apply your texture maps and the projection to the corresponding UV. If you haven't made uv's, create them.